# Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLInputElement> has no method 'processCard'

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, coffeescript

I'm trying to configure a coffeescript class to manage stripe payments. I'm basing my solution on [this tutorial](http://railscasts.com/episodes/288-billing-with-stripe?view=asciicast).

Here's my code:

```
class Subscription  

  count = 0

  page =
    createForm: "form#new_subscription"
    createButton: 'input#create_subscription[type=submit]'
    cardNumber: '#card_number'
    cardCode: '#card_code'
    cardMonth: '#card_month'
    cardYear: '#card_year'
    stripeError: '#stripe_error'

  setupForm: ->
    console.log "binding to submit"
    $(page.createButton).click (e) -> 
      $(page.createButton).attr('disabled', true)
      @processCard()
      return false

  processCard: ->
    console.log "processing card"
    card =
      number: $(page.cardNumber).val()
      cvc: $(page.cardCode).val()
      expMonth: $(page.cardMonth).val()
      expYear: $(page.cardYear).val()

    Stripe.card.createToken(card, subscription.handleStripeResponse);

  handleStripeResponse: (status, response) ->
    if response.error
      console.log "error"
      $(page.stripeError).text(response.error.message)
      $(page.createButton).attr('disabled', false)
      alert ("bla")
    else
      alert("success: " + response.id)

jQuery ->
  Stripe.setPublishableKey($('meta[name="stripe-key"]').attr('content'))
  subs = new Subscription
  subs.setupForm()
```

The problem is that when I click on the submit button, I get the exception:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLInputElement> has no method 'processCard'
```

I believe this is caused by the fact that in the method called by the click event `self` is the html element that triggered the event. while by self I need the javascript object.

any clue on how to fix this?

thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without testing the actual code, it looks like you got the scope wrong.

```
setupForm: ->
  console.log "binding to submit"
  $(page.createButton).click (e) => 
    $(page.createButton).attr('disabled', true)
    @processCard()
    return false
```

By using the fat arrow (`=>`) in `$(page.createButton).click (e) =>` you pass the outer scope `this` inside the callback and can then call `@processCard()` (where `@` will refer to the `new Subscription` instance and not the jQuery `this` reference which is a `HTMLInputElement`).